# Is there a way to decompress GZIP data, then return it to bytes stream and then to the preferred encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, gzip, encode, utf-16

I'm trying to get `gz` file from a website by using the `Requests` library in python.

**My Code:**

```
import zlib
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
     session = requests.Session()
     url_response = session.get(<URL>)
     decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(url_response.content, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

right now the decompressed value that I got is a mixed of chars and bytes,
but I want to decode all the stream to "UTF-16" (when I do it on the current string I got unrecognised chars). 
My idea was to encode to bytes and decode to "UTF-16" but I don't sure if its possible or correct to do that.  
Hope someone could help me to solve this problem, Thanks

**SOLVED**
The file coding was "UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators" so I decode the bytes stream to "utf-8-sig"

Comment: What's the encoding of the raw data you get from the archive?

Comment: @ababak when I checked valid file that I decompress in my computer I got "UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators"

Comment: Use the [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) library. It even allows you to specify a text encoding and will return a text stream yield decoded strings.